# Haskell Linked List Algebraic Datatype

Tags: haskell, linked-list, algebraic-data-types

I was attempting to implement a Haskell algebraic datatype linked list (or perhaps more accurately something linked list-like since I don't know of any way to do memory addressing using Haskell) as well as helper functions for converting to and from Haskell's naive list type and wrote the following:

```
data LinkedList a = Nill | Node a (LinkedList a) deriving Show

hlistTolinkedList :: [a] -> LinkedList a
hlistToLinkedList [] = Nill
hlistToLinkedList x:[] = Node x Nill
hlistToLinkedList x:xs = Node (x) (stringToLinkedList xs)

linkedListToHlist :: LinkedList Char -> [Char]
linkedListToHlist (Node a b) = a ++ linkedListToString b
linkedListToHlist Nill = ''
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
@5:1-5:21 Parse error in pattern: hlistToLinkedList
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my function. Would someone please explain?

Comment: The regular Haskell list type is as likely to be a linked list as your type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is.

Comment: Haskell doesn't promise anything about representation, so I was being cautious. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minimal change needed to make it compile is to simply add some parentheses to the patterns for non-empty lists; e.g.

```
hlistToLinkedList (x:xs) = ...
```

By requiring parentheses for complex patterns, the compiler need not know how many arguments each constructor takes; an important trick for reducing the context sensitivity and promoting separate compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is right, but i think the case, that the list only have on element should be:

```
hlistToLinkedList [x] = Node x Nill
```

And why you don't you recursion for hlistToLinkedList? I think

```
hlistToLinkedList (x:xs) = Node x (hlistToLinkedList xs)
```

Would be a better way to do this :)

Another point is, it's better to use the cons operator instead of concatenation cause in most cases ++ has efficiency of n^2 and : is only n

```
linkedListToHlist (Node a b) = a : linkedListToString b
```